# Missing partial modifier on declaration of type x; another partial declaration of this type exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I have created an empty web application project in visual studio 2010 and have addd the following model class:

```
namespace MessageTest
{
    public class Message
    {
        private String msg;

        public Message(String m)
        {
            this.msg = m;
        }

        public String getMessage()
        {
            return this.msg;
        }

        public void setMessage(String m)
        {
            this.msg = m;
        }

        public bool isEmpty()
        {
            return (this.msg.Length == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

A very simple model class.....but I keep getting the following error when trying to build:

**Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MessageTest.Message'; another partial declaration of this type exists    c:\users\d\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MessageTest\MessageTest\Message.cs**

EDIT: Here is where I use the Class:

```
namespace MessageTest
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Message m = new Message(UserMessage.Text);

            if (m.isEmpty())
            {
                //alert user
            }
            else
            {
                //submit data
                SubmitData(m);
            }


        }

        private void SubmitData(Message msg)
        {
            //submit the data to database    
            var dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();


        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

My .dbml has a table in it called Messages:

**Messages

ID (PK) int(10) auto_inc

Message varchar (100)**

Could this be the issue?

Comment: Seems like you have another type with the same name **Message** that exists in the solution. Search for `Message` in the whole solution.

Comment: I tried changing the class name to something else and it still gave the same error

Comment: Have you searche you whole project? Can you post the code where you try to create an instance of this message?

Comment: From the error description I can say that there is another copy of same project is included. Exclude and remove that copy from the current project.

Comment: Are you using WCF? And did you use the SvcUtil.exe tools?

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace MessageTest
{
    public class Message
    {
```

Change to

```
namespace MessageTest
{
    public partial class Message
    {
```

Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MessageTest.Message'

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't able to reproduce this issue. Try creating a new project in a non-default location(say D: drive) and check out. Hope it may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in my project. 
I've added partial in

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know if my answer apply to your problem exactly or not.*

When I develop website or web application, I sometime go through unexpected error that sometime surely can't be solved by merely checking your code each time.

*So I follow the following pattern before looking code again -*

1. Since all compiled websites goes in Temporary ASP.NET directory, so delete all files and folders from there. On my system for .NET Framework 4.0, the path is - **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files** It is because there exist pre-compiled different copies of same classes in different folders and they sometime conflict issues.
2. Delete Visual Studio 2010 folder in *My Documents*.

** Last for your case, change file name and rebuild it. It will create new compiled file and will mostly solve the problem.